LinkedIn not sharing social previews for even with proper og tags
LinkedIn support basically refused to help me with this, other than linking me to various hand-wavey articles (and SO!). Maybe the SO community can help?
We run a blog engine called Pika (https://pika.page). We're having trouble where our social share images are not resolving when linked in posts on LinkedIn. We used the helpful Post Inspector here:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/
We've found that our blog posts list a 500 error in the inspector. Here's an example:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fpika.pika.page%2Fposts%2Fcanonical-urls
We are confused about this 500 error. The originating post is not 500'ing (https://pika.pika.page/posts/canonical-urls), nor are the share image links 500'ing (https://pika.pika.page/social_previews/posts/canonical-urls.png).
Other "page types" on our engine are not leading to this 500. So here are examples of pages that are not blog posts and display social share images fine on LinkedIn:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fpika.pika.page%2Fguestbook
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fpika.pika.page%2F
We cannot see an obvious differences in our og tags between those working links and the one that is failing with a 500 error.
Note, we also are seeing the same problem with social share images not displaying on Twitter in just this one case type.

The problem ended up being that our Content-Type header was:
Content-Type: */*; charset=utf-8

Instead of:
Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8

Twitter/X, LinkedIn, and Apple Messages choked on */*.
